# JavaScript setTimeout Memory Issue

Tags: javascript, memory, settimeout

I am debugging a code which I think has some memory leak. When running the code in Google Chrome, the browser crashes after a while. I strongly believe the following code (attaching just a template, not the entire code for simplicity) is causing the issue. When I used the Chrome developer tools Timeline tab and watched the memory usage and the memory spikes a lot in the real application. If you notice the code the play is calling transitionTo and transistionTo has a setTimeout function calling play again. I think the memory is not freed because of this. Could anyone please help me in fixing this issue?.

```
    var htmlRotatorTimer = '';

    function play(src){
      // some code here
      transitionTo("gallery", "counter");
      // some code here
    }

    function transitionTo(gallery,index) {      
        // some code here      
       clearTimeout(htmlRotatorTimer);
       htmlRotatorTimer = setTimeout( function(){ play(); }, 1000 );    
       // some code here
     }

play();
```

Here's the longer version of the code

```
// utility for loading slides
        function transitionTo(gallery,index) {

            // preloader (optional) 
            var counterMin = 0;
            if (config.preloader) {
                counterMin = 1;
                if (gallery.length < 3) pause('');                  
            }

            var oldCounter = counter;
            if((counter >= gallery.length) || (index >= gallery.length)) { counter = counterMin; var e2b = true; }
            else if((counter < counterMin) || (index < 0)) { counter = gallery.length-1; var b2e = true; }
            else { counter = index; }



   // added attr speed in div's
//htmlRotatorTimer = ''; 
         var itemSpeed = Number($(gallery[counter]).attr("speed") != undefined ?   $(gallery[counter]).attr("speed") : config.speed);
            //htmlRotatorTimer = setInterval(function(){ play(); },itemSpeed);
            clearTimeout(htmlRotatorTimer);
            htmlRotatorTimer = setTimeout( function(){ play(); }, itemSpeed );

            var rmkName = $(gallery[counter].children).attr("id") != undefined ? 'RMK_' + $(gallery[counter].children).attr("id") : '';
            var isHtml5 = false;
            if (rmkName != '' && eval ('typeof '+ rmkName) == 'object') {                   
                rmkObj = eval(rmkName);     
                isHtml5 = rmkObj.rmkType == 'html5' ? true : false;
                //console.log('html5 is' + rmkObj.rmkType,'obj name' + rmkName, 'typeof:' +(typeof rmkObj));            
            }

    if (config.effect=='fade') {    
        $(gallery[counter])
        .clone()
        .appendTo($cont)
        .hide()                     
        .fadeIn(config.changeSpeed,function(){$('#showbanners.rmkbanner').css({ 'visibility': 'visible'});if($.browser.msie)this.style.removeAttribute('filter');});                        
                if($cont.children().length>1){
                    $cont.children().eq(0).css('position','absolute').fadeOut(config.changeSpeed,function(){$(this).remove();});
                };
            } else if (config.effect=='none') {
                $(gallery[counter])
                    .appendTo($cont);
                if($cont.children().length>1){
                    $cont.children().eq(0).remove();
                };
            };
            // update active class on slide link
            if(config.links){
                $('.'+uniqueClass+'-active').removeClass(uniqueClass+'-active jshowoff-active');
                $('.'+uniqueClass+'-slidelinks a').eq(counter).addClass(uniqueClass+'-active jshowoff-active');
            };

            // reset for html5 objects only
            if (isHtml5) {
                    rmkObj.preload = 'nopreload';
                    rmkObj.Reset();
            }
        };// end function transistionTo

        // is the rotator currently in 'play' mode
        function isPlaying(){
            return $('.'+uniqueClass+'-play').hasClass('jshowoff-paused') ? false : true;
        };

        // start slide rotation on specified interval
        function play(src) {
            if (!finalStop) {
                if (!isBusy()) {
                    counter++;
                    transitionTo(gallery, counter);
                    if (src == 'hover' || !isPlaying()) {
                        //htmlRotatorTimer = setInterval(function(){ play(); },config.speed);
                        clearTimeout(htmlRotatorTimer);
                        htmlRotatorTimer = setTimeout(function(){
                            play();
                        }, config.speed);
                    }
                    if (!isPlaying()) {
                        $('.' + uniqueClass + '-play').text(config.controlText.pause).removeClass('jshowoff-paused ' + uniqueClass + '-paused');
                    }
                };
            };
        };
```

Comment: What is the other code in there, the stuff you listed as "some code here" ?

Comment: This code won't cause high memory usage (let alone a memory leak).

Comment: What is config.changeSpeed set at? If it is more than your config.speed, that certainly can end up being an issue. In addition you have a lot of uncached DOM property retrieval/updates you are doing every second as well, have you considered for example caching some of the element names so they won't have to be searched every single second?

Comment: The config.changeSpeed value is 600 and config.speed is set at 12000. The code is actually a jquery plugin called jShowOff [link](https://github.com/ekallevig/jShowOff/blob/master/jquery.jshowoff.js) that has been modified by the developers where I work. The plugin uses setInterval and also does not have the call to play from transistonTo function.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your call to play is wrong inside the transitionTo function. You are not supplying an argument. By the way, why do you call play() outside as well? If possible, please post the entire code. I'm not sure why you're passing counter string to transitionTo. One suggestion is to use setInterval method in play method like this

```
function play(){
    //existing logic
    setInterval(function(){transitionTo("gallery","counter");},1000); 
}
```

Comment: Using `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout` is in most cases always a bad idea.